# Does Relinux Support UEFI?

Tags: 13.10, uefi, relinux

I need to install xnest and a few other things into an Ubuntu 13.10 - Desktop X86-64 live cd, but I have a UEFI Windows 8 laptop. I know that Remastersys doesn't support UEFI, but I'm wondering if Relinux does?

Comment: what do you mean by supporting UEFI? I don't really know what it is, sorry =P (I'm the relinux guy, so that's why I'm asking you that XD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A developer of relinux can produce absolute answer for your question. You can contact them here and you can ask your question.

https://launchpad.net/relinux and click at ask Question.

Comment: I would thumb up your answer, but I'm not a registered user. Hopefully someone else will on my behalf.

Comment: I will do it but I need time.is it okay for you because that guy will probably sleeping this time.

Answer (score 0):

Just  modify  your  BIOS  config  for  allowing  temporary  disable  the UEFI . Do  your  relinux job -
 after  go  back  and  enable  UEFI.